# How to hide/show an element that is dependent on 2 different elements

Tags: jquery, html, mouseevent, jquery-hover

I have a very tricky UI use-case I can't seem to figure out.

I have 2 divs that are **NOT** nested inside each other (it is important because nesting would have solved it easily).

this is the divs structure:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

This is how they look like by design:

```
-------
|     |
|  A  |
|     |
-------
B is hidden by default

-------------
|     |     |
|  A  |  B  |
|     |     |
-------------
Roll over on A shows B. Rolling over on B or A still shows B

-------
|     |
|  A  |
|     |
-------
Rolling out outside of A & B will hide B
```

I tried to do it with 4 $.on() events (mouseover A, mouseover B, mouseout A, mouseout B). and couldn't manage to solve it. of course this is a simplified example to a complex node structure: A & B contains more elements and aren't siblings.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `mouseleave` event of `a` is fired before mouse enter `b` thus the mouse never has chance to enter `b` to keep it displayed.

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $target = $('.b'),
        timer;
    $('.a').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $target.stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    }, function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
    });

    $target.hover(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q2ubU/)

---